# Button - bring to front

Tags: android, button

I have a button which is part of surfaceView(1).
I have created another view(cropView extends surfaceView(2)) on top of this surfaceView. This view has the height and width to match the parent.

But I want the buttons that are part of (1) to be visible in (2). How do I get this?
I used button.bringToFront()
But this did not seem to help!

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks